# I'd like to apply different sizes to only one font in svelte

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Code made with svelte kit.
In the code below, I want to apply the size of 2xl instead of 5xl only for jejumyeonjo, what should I do?

```
<span
class:font-codystar={fontFamily === "codystar"}
class:font-cormorant={fontFamily === "cormorant"}
class:font-waterfall={fontFamily === "waterfall"}
class:font-jeju-myeongjo={fontFamily === "jejuMyeongjo"}
class:text-5xl={large}
class:text-typography-light={theme === "light"}
class:text-typography-dark={theme === "dark"}
>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could apply the `text-2xl` if `fontFamily` is `jejuMyeongjo`, and `text-5xl` if it is `large` but `fontFamily` is not `jejuMyeongjo`.

```html
<span
  class:font-codystar={fontFamily === "codystar"}
  class:font-cormorant={fontFamily === "cormorant"}
  class:font-waterfall={fontFamily === "waterfall"}
  class:font-jeju-myeongjo={fontFamily === "jejuMyeongjo"}
  class:text-2xl={fontFamily === "jejuMyeongjo"}
  class:text-5xl={large && fontFamily !== "jejuMyeongjo"}
  class:text-typography-light={theme === "light"}
  class:text-typography-dark={theme === "dark"}
>
```